# Broken apt sources when doing apt-get update

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, update-manager

I have the following errors when I attempt to run `sudo apt-get update` on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine:

```
Hit:1 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                                                                           
Hit:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                       
Hit:4 https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com focal InRelease                                                                                             
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                         
Get:6 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]                                                      
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease               
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu focal InRelease    
Ign:9 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:10 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:12 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:9 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [275 kB]
Err:9 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  File has unexpected size (274584 != 274740). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 200.236.31.4 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:274740 [weak]
   - SHA256:d0243a90b0c03eb7d4f65227a6dc70b9c1823651e84efa2dea961e292eff8d40
   - SHA1:c0af1a68c3ff0cdd18d431b8bd17638aa0ef0e18 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:e113059fa103a7d3110cfbbceff74e9b [weak]
  Release file created at: Tue, 30 May 2023 23:15:45 +0000
Get:10 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [16,8 kB]              
Err:10 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata                        
  
Get:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [409 kB]
Err:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  
Get:12 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [944 B]
Err:12 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  
Ign:13 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:14 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:13 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [7.968 B]
Err:13 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  File has unexpected size (7984 != 7968). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 200.236.31.4 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:7968 [weak]
   - SHA256:b94dc8d1bacbedc22aca1aa3ca1958e1daa201843f0e759a485fa4834c0d5bf1
   - SHA1:82c8d9b9a5d0453fe209ab75a16bfff2858d09a5 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:6186e69943a1e6258d8edbcac2e5588c [weak]
  Release file created at: Tue, 30 May 2023 23:17:37 +0000
Get:14 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [30,5 kB]
Err:14 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Fetched 223 kB in 1s (200 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz  File has unexpected size (274584 != 274740). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 200.236.31.4 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:274740 [weak]
    - SHA256:d0243a90b0c03eb7d4f65227a6dc70b9c1823651e84efa2dea961e292eff8d40
    - SHA1:c0af1a68c3ff0cdd18d431b8bd17638aa0ef0e18 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:e113059fa103a7d3110cfbbceff74e9b [weak]
   Release file created at: Tue, 30 May 2023 23:15:45 +0000
E: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/cnf/Commands-amd64.xz  
E: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz  
E: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz  
E: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz  File has unexpected size (7984 != 7968). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 200.236.31.4 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:7968 [weak]
    - SHA256:b94dc8d1bacbedc22aca1aa3ca1958e1daa201843f0e759a485fa4834c0d5bf1
    - SHA1:82c8d9b9a5d0453fe209ab75a16bfff2858d09a5 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:6186e69943a1e6258d8edbcac2e5588c [weak]
   Release file created at: Tue, 30 May 2023 23:17:37 +0000
E: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Can anybody help me into how can I fix this? Here is a picture of Software & Updates. I was trying to remove hashicorp (terraform) ppa, which seems to have started the problem.

[image]